# Enqueue scripts not showing up in head

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am enqueue-ing and registering scripts in my functions.php file. I have three files (2 js and 1 css) but only 2 of the three show up in my head html when I inspect the the output in my browser.

functions.php code

```
/* Quene & register new .css and .js */
function new_styles() {
wp_register_style( 'Wembley-prototype', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/fx_theme.css');
wp_register_script( 'Wembley-prototype', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_register_script( 'Wembley-prototype', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mobile-fix.js', array( 'jquery' ));

wp_enqueue_style( 'Wembley-prototype', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/fx_theme.css');
wp_enqueue_script( 'Wembley-prototype', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'Wembley-prototype', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/mobile-fix.js');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_styles', 20);
```

the mobile-fix.js does not get recognized. Both js files are located in the same js folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register a script, the **`$handle`** (string) (required) Name of the script. Should be **unique** as it is used as a handle for later use with `wp_enqueue_script()`.

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script-1', /* parameters */ );
wp_register_script( 'my-script-2', /* parameters */ );

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-1' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-2' );
```

Comment: You only need to use the `$handle` to enqueue after registering any script, that's also why it should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'slider-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/skrollr.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', false );
```

You can pass the parameter like **true** and **false**

**true** : display scripts on footer

**false** : display scripts on header